# How do I return from an awk script back to the command line?

Tags: cmd.exe, awk

I have a simple awk script, `test1.awk`:

```
{
    x=temp;
    print x;
}
```

When I run it from the Command Prompt with:

```
awk -v temp=hello -f test1.awk
```

I get just a cursor.  I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it writes “hello” and gives another cursor, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> again and it writes “hello” again, etc.  Just goes in an endless loop requiring input from the user, and never comes back to the command prompt.

```
D:\>awk -v temp=hello -f test1.awk

hello

hello

hello

hello
^C
D:\>
```

How do I get it write “hello” (without requiring user input)
and then stop?

Comment: Your example is simultaneously complex and trivial.   It is complex in the sense that it has a variable that must be set via `-v`, or else the program won’t do anything, and then it copies that variable to another variable for no real functional purpose.   It is trivial in the sense that it does nothing but print the value of that variable.   When you’re debugging / troubleshooting, trivial is good and complex is bad.   For trying to get *something* (anything) to work, you should probably start with trivial things like `{ print "Hello"; }`.   For a slightly less trivial example, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Awk reads from stdin.  When you run awk as you are doing above, the awk script is going to process stdin.  You did not pass it in any file to process.  If you have a file, test.in for example, you can run your awk program as follows:

```
awk -v temp=hello -f test1.awk test.in
```

The awk script will process test.in and exit.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, what must I put in test.in?

Comment: What are you trying to do with your awk script?

Comment: I am trying to use awk to interpret an environment variable, net_args: net_args=debug=(123,456) to see if %1 is in there or not.  If it is, then I exit the awk script with exit 1 else exit 0

Comment: so I use: awk -v "temp=%net_args%" -v dflag=%1 -f test.awk test.in.  I put junk into test.in and it works, but just wondered what the significance of test.in is.

Comment: Then your input can be /dev/null, or whatever the equivalent is on Windows.

Comment: In general, awk is used to process text that is typically read in from standard input and written out to standard output.  If you do not need one of them, you can use /dev/null for your input or output.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid a pointless input file, you can put the commands in the END clause:

```
END { x=temp; print x; }
```

Then call the awk script with /dev/null for input, as suggested by Lewis M:

```
awk -v temp=hello -f test1.awk </dev/null
```

Or equivalently in one line:

```
awk -v temp=hello 'END {x=temp; print x;}' </dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

You say you want to run some awk statement(s) once,
without requiring user input, and then stop and return to the command prompt. 
And in your case you are talking about the Command Prompt
(`cmd.exe` in Windows), and not a shell (like bash).

1. [Matthias Gralle’s answer](https://superuser.com/q/1368991/150988#1370127),

   ```
   awk -v temp=hello 'END {x=temp; print x;}' < /dev/null
   ```

   will work in Unix / Linux, and maybe even in a Unix-like shell in Windows,
   but not in `cmd.exe`. 
   Windows doesn’t have a `/dev/null`, *per se.* 
   But Windows does have a null device, called simply `NUL`. 
   (You may add a colon, resulting in `NUL:`, if you want; it’s optional. 
   And, as is typical in Windows, this is case-insensitive,
   so you can say `nul`.) 
   So

   ```
   awk -v temp=hello 'END {x=temp; print x;}' < nul
   ```

   will probably work.

   You don’t say what flavor of `awk` you have on your Windows machine. 
   I have Cygwin, and it turns out that I can do

   ```
   C:\Users\scott> \cygwin64\bin\gawk -v temp=hello 'END {x=temp; print x;}' /dev/null
   hello
   ```

   The difference is that,
   when you say `< filename`,
   the command processor (`cmd.exe`, in your case) processes the filename,
   but, if you leave out the **`<`** and say just *`filename`*,
   the program processes it. 
   And it turns out that Cygwin programs interpret `/dev/null`
   as being the null device, even if they’re being run from Command Prompt.

   Since I don’t know what flavor of `awk` you have on your Windows machine,
   I don’t know whether this will work for you.
2. Matthias came very close to giving you a really good answer. 
   As [Lewis M explained](https://superuser.com/q/1368991/150988#1368994), awk processes input. 
   A typical awk program looks something like

   ```
   BEGIN { something to do (once) at the beginning of the program }
         { something to do on every line of input }
   /foo/ { something to do on every line of input that contains “foo” }
         { something else to do on every line }
               ︙
   END   { something to do (once) at the end of the program }
   ```

   where all of these parts are optional. 
   (And, as you demonstrated in your question, code blocks (a.k.a. actions)
   can be broken up into multiple lines. 
   And short things can be put together on the same line.) 
   Matthias’s idea is to put your statement(s) into the `END` code block,
   *and then to provide a null input, so awk will start,
   execute your statement(s) once, and then exit.* 
   Not that there’s anything wrong with that.[™](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Outing_(Seinfeld)) 
   But it turns out that, if your program consists of a `BEGIN` code block,
   *and nothing else,* then awk executes your statement(s) (once)
   *without even trying to read any input.* 
   So you can say

   ```
   awk -v temp=hello 'BEGIN {x=temp; print x;}'
   ```

   and not need to worry about providing / specifying any input.
3. Here’s an example of a trivial awk program that’s not too trivial:

   ```
   awk '{print "Hello", $0}'
   ```

   If you type this and then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it will say `Hello`. 
   If you type `world`, it will say `Hello world`. 
   If you type `Kitty`, it will say `Hello Kitty`[©](https://www.sanrio.com/pages/copyright). 
   As you know, you can get back to your command prompt
   by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>,
   which basically means “interrupt / stop processing”. 
   But a “nicer” thing to do is to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>,
   which means “this is the end of the input”. 
   This is standard on Unix & Linux, but I can do the following
   (where the ***`bold italic`*** text is what I typed):

   ```
   C:\Users\scott> \cygwin64\bin\gawk '{print "Hello", $0} END {print "Good bye"}'
   sailor
   Hello sailor
   stranger
   Hello stranger
   Ctrl+D
   Good bye
   ```

   whereas, if I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, the `END` code doesn’t run.

   Again, if you’re using something other than Cygwin,
   I don’t know whether this will work for you.

---

Throughout the above examples,
anything that I put between single quotes (`'…'`) can be put into a file,
which you then (as you know) invoke with `-f filename`. 
On Unix, Linux and Cygwin,
I prefer to put my awk programs into shell scripts, like

```
#!/bin/sh
awk '{print "Hello", $0}' "$@"
```

rather than use `.awk` files. 
The `"$@"` lets you pass arguments to awk. 
You might be able to do that in a Windows batch file with `$*`,
but things are never easy in Windows.